# What is the meaning of static const and const in dart programming language?

Tags: android, dart

I watch online tutorial on YouTube in which the tutor says instance variable can be final but cannot be const therefor if you want a Constant at class level then make it static const . My question is what is the need to use static const while we have const keyword whose job is to define a variable that is constant throughout the variable.

Video link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYZqVOH6oSU at 2:24

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](https://news.dartlang.org/2012/06/const-static-final-oh-my.html) :

> "static", "final", and "const" mean entirely distinct things in Dart:
>
> **"static"** means a member is available on the class itself instead of on
>   instances of the class. That's all it means, and it isn't used for
>   anything else. static modifies *members*.
>
> **"final"** means single-assignment: a final variable or field *must* have
>   an initializer. Once assigned a value, a final variable's value cannot
>   be changed. final modifies *variables*.
>
> **"const"** has a meaning that's a bit more complex and subtle in Dart.
>   const modifies *values*. You can use it when creating collections,
>   like const [1, 2, 3], and when constructing objects (instead of new)
>   like const Point(2, 3). Here, const means that the object's entire
>   deep state can be determined entirely at compile time and that the
>   object will be frozen and completely immutable.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is what is the need to use static const while we have const keyword whose job is to define a variable that is constant throughout the variable.

I think the main reason why you need to add the keyword `static` when declaring a `const` field in a class is readability so you are absolutely sure  your understand that this variable will be same in every instance of the class.

Confusion can happen since `final` variables are allowed (and often are) to have different values in each instance of the class since `final` just means "Once assigned a value, a final variable's value cannot be changed.".

Since `const` means compile-time constant, it will always stay the same for all instances of a class which means it will always be `static`. But to make that fully clear for the developer, we need to write `static` even if the compiler could figure that out itself.

But again, that is only my guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose `const` on a member did not require `static`, and you had:

```dart
class Foo {
  const k = 42;
}
```

How do you access it?

`Foo.k` should be legal; since the value is always the same, you shouldn't need to construct a `Foo` object first.

What about `Foo().k`?  Since there's no `static` keyword, it *looks* like it might be legal too.  But if that's allowed, then there are bunch of cases you need to consider and define behaviors for:

```dart
Foo fooInstance = null;
print(fooInstance.k);
print(fooInstance?.k);

class Derived extends Foo {
  const k = 9;
}

fooInstance = Derived();
print(fooInstance.k);
```

It seems simpler and clearer to me to require that `const` members also be `static`.